# GA tracking with additional URL parameters

Tags: google-analytics, branch.io

Something I cannot find information about in the GA tracking documentation of branch.io is how to attach parameters other than the default GA ones to a link?

For example on top of UTM tracking our company uses custom URL parameters like ?acc=amex in order to provide special access pages on web that triggers certain things. Since in Branch we only have "Channel" "Campaign" and "tags" then I'm wondering would branch pass those custom link parameters and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do pass custom link parameters to Google Analytics and this requires a custom webhook implementation. As this requires more information from your end, I would request you to send an email to integrations@branch.io to take this forward.